# Hive table's are on dataproc cluster store in GCS bucket and I want to store data to another gcs bucket using dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc

My hive table's are on dataproc cluster store in GCS bucket and I want to store data to another gcs bucket after performing some transformation using dataflow.
So Need help on how to proceed.

Comment: Is it possible for you to ignore Hive and simply read from GCS with Dataflow?